# Buscar elemento CLASS com value em espaço

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Estou fazendo uma automação com Selenium C# e o única referencia padrão da tag é uma class referenciada por outras classes:

```
<div class="slds-form-element slds-form-element_readonly">
```

Já tentei:

```
.FindElement(By.ClassName("slds-form-element slds-form-element_readonly"))
```

Porém me retorna um erro dizendo que não é possivel localizar class com espaços

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use da seguinte forma:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='slds-form-element slds-form-element_readonly']"));
```

Ou:

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='slds-form-element slds-form-element_readonly']"));
```